# What about questions already answered elsewhere?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions, site-crossover

What should we do about questions that are already answered on another SE site? I'm thinking of this [one example answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6870/how-do-i-upgrade-openssl/6874#6874). It's normally done that way when the link is external to SE, or it's normally left as a comment. How to deal with answers like that?

Answer (score 4):

I think the question should be moved to serverfault and then closed as a duplicate

rationale:
Obviously, this question is related to servers. And obviously it's already been answered on the serverfault website

Comment: Any computer can be called 'server', which would mean unix.se.com (and many others) should be merged into serverfault.

Answer (score 3):

Generally we expect questions to be tailored to the audience and community of the particular site.

Even if it is the "same" question the answers and focus will be different per site.

Exact duplicates or cross-posting is, of course, strongly discouraged.