# What is an appropriate way to indicate a previously asked question needs to be readdressed?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, meta

**I'm about to use a specific example to highlight a general question**

I recently posted an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325934/395595) to [What to do with cross-site duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4708/395595)  That question was originally asked, and a best-answer chosen, in 2009.

A lot of time has passed and while I believe the question is still relevant and should be asked again today, the answers are now obsolete.

Others have tried to ask the same question because the issue needs to be readdressed.

- [Are similar questions allowed on two sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7000/are-similar-questions-allowed-on-two-sites?noredirect=1&lq=1) (2009)
- [What about questions already answered elsewhere?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77829/what-about-questions-already-answered-elsewhere?noredirect=1&lq=1) (2011)
- [What to do about the same question on multiple sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195916/what-to-do-about-the-same-question-on-multiple-sites?noredirect=1&lq=1) (2013)
- [What to do when my question has a duplicate on another Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177422/what-to-do-when-my-question-has-a-duplicate-on-another-stack-exchange-site?noredirect=1&lq=1) (2013)
- [What’s the Accepted Procedure for questions that have been answered on another Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199693/what-s-the-accepted-procedure-for-questions-that-have-been-answered-on-another-s?noredirect=1&lq=1) (2013)
- [Cross-site duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187607/cross-site-duplicates?noredirect=1&lq=1) (2013)
- [Closing duplicates between StackOverflow and StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224120/closing-duplicates-between-stackoverflow-and-stackexchange?noredirect=1&lq=1) (2014)
- [What should I do with question that has been answered on another site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216598/what-should-i-do-with-question-that-has-been-answered-on-another-site?noredirect=1&lq=1) (2014)
- [Cross-stack duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308089/cross-stack-duplicates?noredirect=1&lq=1) (2018)
- [Should I paraphrase the cross-site duplicate when posting it as an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318178/395595) (2018)

All in all, there are 36 questions linked back to that 2009 original (and I haven't tried to count the number of questions linked as duplicates to those 36...).  It appears to me that this is an issue that needs to be readdressed.

**Question:** What is the proper procedure for identifying any previous Meta question that should no longer be automatically used as a VTC:Duplicate target but, instead, should be legitimately re-considered?

Answer (score 5):

The procedure is the same as that on main Q&A sites. On main sites, you can re-ask a question and not have it closed as a duplicate as long as you [clearly state that you're aware of the existing question and explain why the answers there didn't work for you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20042/if-you-are-not-satisfied-with-answers-on-someone-elses-question-should-you-ask).

In a similar vein, you can re-raise an issue that you think needs discussion again, as long as you make it clear that you're aware of existing discussions regarding the issue and enumerate why you don't believe the discussion outcomes in the top answers apply today anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you:

> ... believe the question is still relevant and should be asked again
>   today, the answers are now obsolete.

When I see a Q&A in which I think the question is still relevant, but the answers are obsolete, the actions I take are:

1. Upvote the question because I think it is still useful
2. Downvote any answers that I think are no longer useful
3. Consider offering a bounty giving this as the reason why I am offering it:

> **Current answers are outdated**
>
> The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given
>   recent changes.

Comment: My only problem with this method is that the originally selected "best answer" remains selected - biasing people who think it's still relevant when it is not.  If starting a bounty due to answers being outdated deselected the "best answer" (requiring a new answer to be selected as "best") it would be the perfect solution.

Comment: @JBH - I think that implementation of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268666/215590 would help get to your perfect state.

Comment: It would and I've upvoted it, but I note that Q is dated 2015.  Enhancements seem to be very slow to implement.  At this point, I have trouble believing a single post, lost on Meta since 2015, would be recognized by SO as something they should be looking at for implementation.  In a sense, that Q is suffering the same problem as the one I want to bring again to the fore.  It's lost in the forest.